# Open a "modal" window

Tags: html, css

How can i make when I click on the card it opens a "modal window" with information about the product.

```
       <div class="card">

            <div class="imgBox">
            <img src="./img/bau.png" alt="Produto" class="mouse">
            </div>
        
            <div class="contentBox">
            <h3>Plugin</h3>
            <h2 class="price">25.<small>00</small> BRL</h2>
            <a href="#" class="buy">Comprar Agora!</a>
            </div>
        
        </div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches. And there is no real right or wrong here either.
The approach has to fit your application. If you always try to keep the approach somewhat abstract, there is nothing fundamentally wrong with it.

In the example below, I have taken the linked modal example from the comment
below your question and adapted the following.

1. added a data object in which I manage the corresponding contents of the modal.Here you can also use an API call against an interface.
2. I have assigned an EventListener to all buttons.
3. The parts that are variable in the modal are exchanged with the corresponding content when clicked.

Done!

```js
const modalData = [
  {id: 1, title: "Title One", content: "bla"},
  {id: 2, title: "Title Two", content: "bla blu"},
];

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 

btns.forEach(b => {
  b.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    const dataId = e.target.getAttribute("data-id")

    const data = modalData.filter(m => m.id == dataId);

    const modalTitle = document.querySelector("#myModal .title");
    const modalContent = document.querySelector("#myModal .content");
    modalTitle.innerHTML = data[0].title;
    modalContent.innerHTML = data[0].content;
  })
});


// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

  <h2>Animated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>

  <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
  <button class="myBtn" data-id="1">Open Modal 1</button>
  <button class="myBtn" data-id="2">Open Modal 2</button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h2 class="title">Modal Header</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body content">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```